# Memory Configuration in Windows CE(OS design )

Tags: windows-ce

I am new in windows ce. I am working on "friendly-arm mini2440" board. I have programmed the board and I feel that windows can not use all of my SDRAM and I feel Same problem for NAND flash. I looked at system properties and it shows that RAM memory is 30640 KB. In the BSP, I looked at file 
C:\WINCE600\PLATFORM\Mini2440\Files\config.bib
and it contains following lines:

MEMORY
    NK      80200000  01e00000  RAMIMAGE
    RAM     82000000  01e00000  RAM
;    FLASH   92000000  00100000  RESERVED

I convert 01e00000 from hexidecimal to decimal and it is equal to 31457280. I think that file config.bib plays an important role in configuring RAM and Flash. but when I changed it and I tried to build the os design, build process ends with error. I don't know how to solve this problem. I dont have the board's address memory map too.

Comment: I found a useful page which may be can help myself. the link is as follows: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ce_base/archive/2006/09/01/735940.aspx